# Django inspectdb miss POSTGRESQL materialized views

Tags: django, inspectdb

All other tables are correctly converted to models but both the views and the materialized views seems to be skipped.

Am I missing something or views and materialized views aren't managed by

`./manage.py inspectdb`

?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work since 1.8, on 1.7 it worked with MySQL views. Very annoying.